# C++/CLIでRTP/RTSPのライブラリを探しています。

Tags: c++-cli

C++/CLIでRTSPサーバに対してRequestLineを送信し、返って来るデータを取得するライブラリ又はサンプルプログラムを探しています。
ダウンロードできるサイト等があれば教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

[JRTPLIB](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib)が多くのプロジェクトで使われているようです。
[LIVE555](http://live555.com/)も知られているようです。コマンドラインのツールもあります。